# ionic build for browser getting white screen

Tags: ionic-framework

I use this command to build an ionic application for the browser.

```
ionic build --prod --release
```

After that, I copied the `www` folder to my server, but it just gave me a blank screen and there was this error on the console.

output Picture:

[image]

Comment: A 404 error means file not found. Have you uploaded all of the javascript and CSS it is missing?

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  It's policy here not to to use images for this purpose, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.  You're most likely to get an answer if you include a full [mcve] *as text* showing exactly how to reproduce the issue.  See: [ask].